# 8 - How to set page title for certain nodes?

Tags: theming, 8, entities, routes

I've created the following codes:

The first one is **mymodule/mymodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

The second one is **mymodule/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php** with following code

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\eq_site\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.canonical')) {
      $route->setDefault('_title_callback', '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::title');
    }
  }
}
```

**mymodule/src/Controller/MyModuleController.php** contains following code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityViewController;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Returns responses for Node routes.
 */
class MyModuleController extends EntityViewController {
  /**
   * The _title_callback for the page that renders a single node.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node
   *   The current node.
   *
   * @return string
   *   The page title.
   */
  public function title(EntityInterface $node) {
    return 'Foo : '. $this->entityManager->getTranslationFromContext($node)->label();
  }
}
```

Devel route detail is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [__CLASS__] => Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
    [path] => /node/{node}
    [host] => 
    [schemes] => Array
        (
        )

    [methods] => Array
        (
            [0] => GET
            [1] => POST
        )

    [defaults] => Array
        (
            [_controller] => \Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController::view
            [_title_callback] => \Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::title
        )

    [requirements] => Array
        (
            [node] => \d+
            [_entity_access] => node.view
            [_method] => GET|POST
        )
```

But, page title has not changed. 
What I do wrong?
And how to determine the node type?

Comment: This is because of this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2359901 and the patch tries for the most part to discourage entities to use #title.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to get rid of #title for nodes. By removing `EntityViewController::buildTitle` from #pre_render you don't have #title in the top level anymore, but then #title bubbles up from the title field. If you remove this you get an error in node preprocess.

Comment: @4k4, thanks for you reply. I guess to be better to generate a title on the create node event.

Comment: Yes, but until the issue is resolved you might need to change the title twice, in route and node build. Breadcrumbs for example use only the title from the route.